# saving an instance of a model with auto_now_add in Django returns error message Column 'xxx' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, django

I must be doing something very wrong or this error doesn't make any sense to me.   I have an object **Location**:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'location'

    location_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    apt_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField()
    created = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

here this is my code for inserting a new or updating an existing location record:

```
class LocationList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        location_dict = request.data
        if 'location_id' not in location_dict:
            okStatus = status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        else:
            okStatus = status.HTTP_200_OK
        location = Location(**location_dict)
        location.save()
        return Response(LocationSerializer(location).data, status=okStatus)
```

Inserts work fine, but everytime an update happens, I get the error "Column 'created' cannot be null".  My online research seems to point me to the fact that this was a bug which has been long fixed.  I expect the update to pass since the 'created' field was set to auto_now_add, which means Django should set that field once upon insert and leave it on any subsequent update.  I do not know why Django is trying to set that column to null or any other value on update, because I expect Django to not update the column at all.  I am using MySQL as database.

Comment: In the line `if 'location_id' not in location_dict:`, do the quotes need to exist?

Comment: I think so, but I don't think that would have caused the error, the error is thrown at the line "location.save()"

Comment: you could get rid of it in your code and instead use MySQL default values. You can edit the column to get the value of NOW() on insert, that way the DB will handle it instead of your code.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your problem is in the " created column " try this steps :-

1) add null=True inside the created column

2) run :$ python"select version" manage.py makemigrations "appName or keep it empty"

3) run :$ python"V" manage.py sqlmegrate "aapName" " file version" >
     check the file version in the app directory type it like this "0001"

4) run :$ python"V" manage.py migrate "appName"

after these steps ur db should be updated, last step is to remove (null=True from created column ) and start project.